# Is it correct to calculate a within-person estimate for the effect of a binary predictor on an outcome variable in a linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have been reading several articles on the disaggregation of between and within effects in mixed models, such as Curran and Bauer's (2011) excellent article in which they state "More careful work is needed to understand how *zb*i and *zw*ti can best be obtained when the TVC is binary or ordinal" where in this case *zb*i refers to the between effect estimate and *zw*ti to the within effect estimate of a time varying covariate *z*. Forgive my long-winded question but I think it important to carefully convey my query by laying the baseline for what I understand of the topic and also by putting it into context first, so my concerns are clear.

In my research I am exploring the effect of a time-varying binary covariate (social media use) on a continuous outcome in sleep duration (mins). Both were assessed daily over two weeks, and participants could either report no social media use before bed (0) or social media use before bed (1) as the two levels of the predictor. It is clearly of intrinsic value to disagreggate the between and within effects of my variable in case they are different. For example, more average social media use might correlate with poorer quality sleep in general (between effect), however, people might also use social media as a tool to wind-down at night when they are feeling stressed and so higher than normal use might in fact be associated with better quality sleep (within effect). In reality I don't expect this to be the case, nonetheless it's important to disagregate the effects (this point has been made by a reviewer).

Ordinarily the between-persons component is generated by obtaining an estimate for person-specific mean values of a predictor whereas the within-persons component is generated by calculating an estimate for the person-specific deviation for that variable (i.e., the value of said predictor on any given night minus the person-specific mean of that predictor).

For a continuous variable (for arguments sake lets pretend this is the number of minutes spent using social media), a person-specific mean would therefore be the average value of the predictor (average amount of time spent using social media) across all 14 nights. The person-specific deviation for that variable, as mentioned above, is calculated by subtracting this mean from the individual values on each night to represent the number of minutes spent on social media relative to a person's indivual average time spent on social media. Negative scores on this person-specific deviation variable therefore represent less time on social media than they would normally spend, whereas positive values represent more time on social media than they would normally spend.

The issue arises when considering how this looks for a binary predictor. The person-specific mean is no longer an average amount of time spent on social media before bed, it instead becomes the proportion of nights in which they used social media before bed. This is still comparable to the person-specific mean of a continuous variable because a person with a higher individual mean still roughly equates to more time spent on social media over the course of the two weeks. An example of some person-specific means include someone who never used social media (scored 0 on all possible occasions and therefore has a mean of 0), someone who always used social media (scored 1 on all possible occasions and therefore has a mean of 1), or anyone in between whereby scores closer to 1 represent a higher mean (proportion) of days where social media was used before bed. No problem here. However, the person-specific deviation is then still calculated in the same way as for a continuous variable (i.e., the person-specific mean is substracted from the individual scores for each day). Given the individual scores can only be 0 or 1, the resulting person-specific deviation variable then depends on how high or low their mean was. Those with higher mean scores (let's take a mean of .93 for example), would have 14 days of data, 13 days of which they used social media before bed and 1 day in which they did not. On the days they did, their person-specific deviation would be .07 (1 - .93), and therefore represent only a slight departure away from their mean performance, in favour of having used social media more than they normally would. The 1 day they did not would have a score of -.93 (0 - .93) and therefore represent a drastic departure away from their mean performance, in favour of using social media less than they normally would.

Thus plotting these scores for all participants (as seen below) would illustrate that higher magnitudes of negative scores represent a more unusual **non-performance** of the behaviour. But higher magnitudes of positive scores represent a more unusual **performance** of the behaviour. Doesn't this then make the coefficient that is generated from the model unintepretable? Because a one unit change in this person-specific deviation variable is not equivalent at all points of the scale. For instance a one unit change from -1 to 0 represents a change from very unusual abstince to performing (or not performing) the behaviour as you normally would, whereas a one unit change from 0 to 1 represents performing (or not performing) the behaviour as you normally would to very unusual performance.

[image]

I have looked through other sources but cannot find an answer to whether or not it is truly acceptable to extract a within-persons effect in this manner for binary predictor variables. The only thing I have to go off is Curran and Bauer's advice from above. Is anyone able to advise me why/why not I am safe to interpret the within-person coefficient for my binary variable like you would for a continuous variable?

### References

Curran, P. J., & Bauer, D. J. (2011). The disaggregation of within-person and between-person effects in longitudinal models of change. Annual review of psychology, 62, 583–619. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.psych.093008.100356